# Matlab histogram of function with generated values

Tags: matlab, histogram

I want to represent the histogram with Y = e(X), where X is a random number from a chosen interval: generate m arrays with n values in the interval [a,b] and represent the histogram of the m arrays.

So far, I have the following:

```
    arrays=rand(n,m)
    data = mean(arrays)
    hist(data, 50, "facecolor", "g", "edgecolor", "r")
```

which builds a histogram based on m arrays with n values. I do not know how to take into consideration the interval [a,b] or how to display this function Y = e^E(X). Any hints and help will be well received. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with `e^E(x)`? `e=exp` i guess and `E(x)`?

Comment: And your interval do you want to take it into account when computing the mean or when displaying it?

Comment: X will be a random value from the interval [a,b], the rest can be simplified let's say to f(X) - function to compute the Y value

Comment: when compute the mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab's `rand` returns pseudo-random numbers in interval (0, 1). You may transform this interval to (*a*, *b*) — and not to [*a*, *b*] — via:

```
arrays = (b-a)*rand(n,m) + a
```

Of course, this is provided `a` and `b` variables are defined.

On the other hand, displaying `n` mean values of `m` samples each for a distribution does not say much about the underlying distribution, does it? What you'd want is a histogram of a single array, with bins in the interval (*a*, *b*). Type:

```
 >>doc hist
```

on your Matlab console to see how to do this, or check the help from the [latest version](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/hist.html).

Comment: I don't agree with your "On the other hand..." part. Let's say you repeat a measurement with 300 datapoints 100 times. THen you could easily compare the 100 mean values of the 300 points with each other. Giving you a significance of your data or am i wrong?

Comment: @TheMinion I didn't write it doesn't say *anything*. I wrote it doesn't say *much*. Please allow me to formulate this as a rhetorical question: how much information would you infer from 100 mean values, compared to the information from counting in 20 "equal" bins, for those 3000 samples?